# Get Current raster position in opengl es 1.1

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-to-opengles

How we can get Current raster position in opengl es 1.1 like in OpenGl where we do this by calling glGet with argument GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no concept of the *raster position* in OpenGL ES, there's really nothing to get.  In ES, you'd need to manage the positions of geometry, and track this in the application, as compared to having OpenGL (ES) manage it for you.